# Remove @gmail.com from WordPress username

Tags: users

is there a code that I can put in the function of my site, so that if a user's username is gmail@gmail.com, it will be targeted like this, for example, mohammad11@gmail.com, it will be automatic, this is mohammad11. Thank you for your help.

Comment: how or where do you plan to use this new string/name?

Comment: Hello, for WordPress, sign up for Gmail